# AbstractController::ActionNotFound for destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am facing a weird problem
when I am trying to destroy active record it is giving this error.

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /photos/6

The action 'destroy' could not be found for PhotosController
```

here is what my controller look like

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
     before_filter :authenticate_user!

....
....

  def delete
      @photo = current_user.photos.find(params[:id])
      @photo.destroy
      redirect_to photos_path
     end
```

and if I perform the same actions using console it is working fine(the record is getting deleted successfully ).

This is my routes file look like.

```
 resources :photos, :only => [:index, :show, :new, :create] do
   post 'upload', :on => :collection
 end
```

I know I have not included :destroy in resources please suggest me how to insert :destroy action to delete photos

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using `resources :photo`.
The action should be `destroy` and not `delete`, as per the [Rais Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).
The seven default actions are: `index, new, create, show, edit, update and destroy`

```
 def destroy
  @photo = current_user.photos.find(params[:id])
  @photo.destroy
  redirect_to photos_path
 end
```

You can also see the [available routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#inspecting-and-testing-routes) by:

```
rake routes
```

**EDIT**

The problem is here: `:only => [:index, :show, :new, :create]`, which is saying to rails: do not create `destroy`, `edit` or `update` routes.

To solve the problem, you can add destroy to it `:only => [:index, :show, :new, :create, :destroy]` or use `:except` instead: `:except => [:edit, :update]`

If you don't want to limitate the resources:

```
resources :photos do
  post 'upload', :on => :collection
end
```

**EDIT 2** - I don't really understand why you are trying to use `delete` instead of `destroy`, However, if you have a good reason for it:

```
resources :photos :only => [:index, :show, :new, :create] do
  post 'upload', :on => :collection
  get 'delete', :on => :member
end
```

In this way you will have the `delete_photo_path`, which can be used in your show view:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', delete_photo_path(@photo) %>
```

Finally, the action delete should looks like:

```
def delete
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  @photo.destroy
  redirect_to photos_path
end
```

Comment: I have tried using delete action also !! even if i use delete action it is pointing to the same error

"The action 'destroy' could not be found for PhotosController"

Comment: could you please include the output of rake routes in your question.

Comment: yes I have included my routes file code. can you please explain me how to insert destroy in routes separately to delete photos

Comment: yes i have tried removing :only => [:index, :show, :new, :create]
and by adding :only => [:index, :show, :new, :create, :destroy] but no luck
i want delete action but not post. only for destroy and rest of actions i want post

Comment: `get 'delete', :on => :member` will add the route for delete action

Comment: yes i did but it is taking me to show action!! with this error
"Couldn't find Photo with id=delete [WHERE "photos"."user_id" = 1]"

Comment: there is something else going on... you should use the default resources, so the action is `destroy` and not `delete`. Anyway, edit your question with the current routes, controller(destroy and show actions) and the view (link to call de action)

Comment: change `@photo = current_user.photos.find(params[:id])` to `@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])`

Answer (score 0):

if you have resource of photo then action name should be destroy, not delete. and if not then please check your routes.

Seven default action that are generated by scaffolding are follow

1. index
2. new
3. edit
4. create
5. update
6. show
7. destroy # not delete